# Parsing JSON object with $.parseJSON returns null

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, json, coffeescript

I am requesting a JSON response via `$.ajax` in my rails project.

```
jQuery ->
  testAjax()


testAjax = ->
  $.ajax
    url: "/gmap/test"
    data: "id=2"
    type: "GET"
    dataType: "json"
    complete: (data_response) ->
      result = $.parseJSON(data_response)
      alert(result.name)
```

I seem to get a correct json string back (according to Firebug console), which looks like this:

```
{"name":"Space Needle","latitude":47.620471,"longitude":-122.349341}
```

However, I get an error complaining "TypeError: result is null"

If I use

```
alert(data_response.responseText)
```

in the `complete` function, I get the json string. So the problem seems to be the parsing. (???)

Comment: Is the return definitely a string. You get that error thrown if parseJSON is used to parse something that is already JSON (has the correct headers set).

Comment: You don't need to parse the JSON, setting `dataType: "json"` does that automatically, which means you are trying to parse a JavaScript object.

Comment: put in real code, not psuedo code

Comment: It's coffeescript not pseudo code.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss That is real code, it's `coffeescript` LOL

Comment: @Korikulum If I do `alert(data_response.name)` it says `undefined`

Comment: @Alex Your query has sparked an idea, I tried:
`alert($.parseJSON(data_response.responseText).name)`
and that works. Still, it seems silly to convert the JSON object into a string to then parse it... What's wrong with the original object?

Comment: @donsteffenski Now, I'm not sure about this, but as far as I can tell, the problem seems to be that `alert(data_response.name)` gets translated into `return alert(data_response.name)`. Maybe you should try `alert(data_response.name),return`.

Comment: @Korikulum Thanks, but that doesn't seem to help. Also, the `alert` method does get called and works in some cases as explained above.

Comment: @donsteffenski Yea, sorry I guess I need more coffee this morning :)

Comment: @Korikulum the complete callback doesn't contain the parsed json response, it's first argument is a jqXHR object. :

Comment: @KevinB You're right, I was thinking about the success callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dooh! Thanks @KevinB, your comment about `success` and `complete` has solved it. It's so simple, use the former instead of the latter:

```
jQuery ->
  testAjax()
  #initialize()


testAjax = ->
  $.ajax
    url: "/gmap/test"
    data: "id=2"
    type: "GET"
    contentType: "application/json"
    dataType: "json"
    success: (data) ->
      alert(data.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of the complete callback is a `jqXHR` object. Try this instead:

```
#Scope the result outside of the testAjax function
result = null

testAjax = ->
  $.ajax
    url: "/gmap/test"
    data: "id=2"
    type: "GET"
    dataType: "json"
    success: (data) ->
      #set the data to your result
      result = data
    complete: ->
      alert result.name
```

Feel free to edit my response to convert my changes to valid coffeescript.

Comment: @donsteffenski Replying to your suggested edit(which got rejected by other reviewers), yes that's what I intended.

Comment: Perhaps it's a good time to learn coffeescript if you're going to answer questions in this topic, @Kevin? :)

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte I don't see a reason for coffeescript to exist to be honest, but thanks for fixing it!

Comment: I thought the same thing until I started using it. You'd be surprised how much less code needs to be written and how nice some of the added language features are (default params, splats, list comprehensions, etc.). That said, you may be better off with vanilla js or even TypeScript. :)